# Is precooked white corn meal degerminated?

Tags: corn

I bought a Kroger brand white corn meal that is precooked. I do not know what precooked means but my question is "does anyone know if the whole grain is used in this product or is it degerminated".

I would rather have the nutrition and fiber of the entire grain but am not at all familiar with this product. My research shows there is also a P.A.N. brand that describes itself also as "precooked" white corn.

Comment: Are you talking about masarepa, or some other variety of precooked white corn meal?  Maybe you can share a photo of the label?

Comment: @FuzzyChef  Thank you for asking. Here is a similar product https://paisausa.com/products/harina-p-a-n-precooked-corn-meal  This is an experiment I am trying to make salt free corn bread similar to my mother made in the 1950's  but have not yet success yet. My plan is to add water until it is mush then coat it with olive oil to keep from burning and bake it until it has the consistancy of corn bread,

Comment: Why not make a regular cornbead with no salt @Sedumjoy?

Comment: I thought the whole grain might be a healthier choice. Also it's hard to eliminate sodium from traditional cornbread because they use sodium bicarbonate or baking powder which has sodium bicarbonate as an ingredient. I try to cut some salt when possible because I have edema. No worries the question is a bit off the beaten path.

Comment: i will try it as is  thank you ....probably i need to close the question so people don't use any time on it.

Comment: You do not want to use precooked cornmeal of any kind for cornbread.  The grain you bought is meant for arepas, not bread.

Comment: @FuzzyChef. Thank you! I am  making arepas. I just mix and bake in the oven in flat shape like a pancake. Can make a sandwhich with them or eat as is and no salt. I coat with olive oil before cooking  a very small amount and it gives it a cruncy crust on the outside. I will make this instead of cornbread. That being said the mystery remains!! No one has gotten back to me from Kroger. No one seems to know what precooked cornmeal is. Corn is a very complex product. I think I need a flow chart of nixtamalization and degermination. :) :)

Comment: Corn *is* the primary caloric food for like 1/5 of the world's population.  That tends to make for a lot of variation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, the specific type of precooked cornmeal you're working with is called [masarepa](https://www.thespruceeats.com/masarepa-precooked-corn-flour-for-making-arepas-3029290), and is used in the cuisine of northern South America.

Masarepa is degerminated.

Comment: Thank you FuzzyChef. You do good research and that is a good article explaining Masarepa. I have to tell you they sure taste good. It's hard to believe I found something that I can eat in abundance and not get a bunch of salt and at the same time taste good. I can have my cake and eat it too just in this one case. :)

Comment: @Sedumjoy I think that the pre-cooking will alter the form of the starch granules in the cornmeal, so you'd never get the rise and texture out this type of cornmeal that you want for cornbread. If you want the low sodium form of bicarbonate, look for ones that are specifically potassium bicarbonate - seems that Walmart has food grade powders available on their website.

Comment: @bob1....Thank you for the heads up bob1.